# Fast alternative to built-in sort/4

Tags: sorting, prolog, code-snippets

I'm looking for an alternative to `sort/4`. The built-in version is currently unavailable to me.

If it was available, the syntax I need would look like this `sort(1, @>=, List, Sorted)`. The elements in the list look like this `([Value:x:y,z:a]:[], ...)`. The result has to be sorted in descending order according to the Value parameter.

An example list for testing purposes:

> [ [16:x:y,z:a]:[], [64:x:y,z:a]:[], [4:x:y,z:a]:[], [1024:x:y,z:a]:[], [0:x:y,z:a]:[], [100:x:y,z:a]:[], [50:x:y,z:a]:[], [-100:x:y,z:a]:[], [0:x:y,z:a]:[] ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the key, put it in front of your structures, call sort/2 (or msort/2, to avoid losing duplicates) then strip the key from the sorted list.

The same code (a list visit) can be used to both put the key in front and remove it. The last step will reverse the list, to get descending order.

```
alternative_sort(Structs, Sorted) :-
  structs_keyed(Structs, Keyed),
  sort(Keyed, Temp),
  structs_keyed(TempR, Temp),
  reverse(TempR, Sorted).

structs_keyed(Sorted, Temp) :- % assume library(yall) available
  maplist([S,K]>>(S=([Value|_]:_),K=Value/S), Sorted, Temp).
```

to be true, since the sort key value it's the first value element, could reduce to just

```
alternative_sort(Structs, Sorted) :-
  sort(Structs, Ascending),
  reverse(Ascending, Sorted).
```

Comment: Thanks for the short version!